# Открытие файла без расширения в С++

Tags: c++, файлы, visual-c++, логирование

Есть файл, путь - C:\Windows\System32\config\SYSTEM
"SYSTEM" - сам файл, лог, в С++ пишу такой код, но файл невозможно открыть:

```
std::string line;
    std::ifstream log;
    log.open ("C:\\Windows\\System32\\config\\SYSTEM");
```

Подскажите, как это сделать? Или есть другой лог файл, из которого можно считать, например, сколько папок или файлов удалено и т.д.

Comment: Скорее всего просто недостаточно прав, все-таки системная папка...

Comment: Как тогда можно отследить действия пользователя? Нужно написать курсовую, а я даже не представляю как...

Comment: Вы в Windows XP/2000 в обычном режиме пытаетесь открыть файл реестра, да еще и системную ветвь? Даже у администратора нет права доступа к этому файлу на работающей системе. Возможно, в Safe Mode дадут прочитать, но тоже сомневаюсь. Да и с чего Вы решили, что в этой ветке будет информация про действия обычных пользователей? На каком уровне отследить действия пользователя? Может хватит просто кейлоггера (раньше по интеренетам много валялось для XP)?

Comment: К этому файлу - вряд ли даже при работе от имени администратора... Шибко он секретный :) А что вы в нем собирались увидеть?

Comment: Работаю на Win10, отследить на уровне сколько папок создано, удалено, какие или сколько файлов удалялось. В таком духе. Подскажите, где искать лог, сам ничего не могу найти

Comment: @Luxoff А разве в этом файле есть такая информация?

Comment: Я предполагал, что есть. Кто может подсказать, где искать этот лог
?